# How to find the position of an item of a list in python?

Tags: python, list, colors, position, variable-length-array

I have two lists. The first list has a specific length and the second list has unstable length. I want to assign the items from two lists.
I use `colour_index = sel_pos%(len(colours))`. The sel_pos is the item's position from the unstable list.
How to find the position every time?

Comment: `list.index()` ? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-given-a-list-containing-it-in-python
Or I haven't understood the question... Please clarify

Comment: the question is not at all clear.

Comment: Can you provide a code sample, so we can more easily understand your issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `l.index(n)` to find index of `n` in list `l`.

```
>>> x = [1,3,7]
>>> x.index(3)
1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
colour_index = selections.index(txt)%(len(colours))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Index function which is get the element and return the index of it in the list:

```
indexNumber = MyList.Index(Element)
```

Comment: `index` is case sensitive